# Slicer Interaction Between Visuals

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a set of visuals showing orders that are at risk of not delivering on time. A bar chart shows the representation of just today. I also have an area chart that shows a trend over time.

Each order is associated with a sales rep. The default view shows all orders across all reps. However, I have a slicer that allows the visuals to be filtered by rep. If I chose rep A, I see the bar chart change to show only today's orders that belong to them and the area chart shows their trends over time.

Most of this works fine, with the exception of the bar chart. I would like the bar chart to ALWAYS show the latest data from the last report run...lets say yesterday 6/21/23. If a rep has no orders at risk for the last run of the report, then the bar chart would say 0.

With my current measure:

```
At Risk on Last Run = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Monitor Orders'[Order #]),'Monitor Orders'[Type] = "At Risk",'Monitor Orders'[Run Date] = MAX('Monitor Orders'[Run Date]))
```

the bar chart updates to the last day the rep had at risk orders on the report and shows those values rather than just zero's for today. I understand why it is doing this...I am filtering orders by rep with the slicer and pulling the max date from that filtered set.

I have attempted to fix this by creating a measure that is calculated independently of the slicer.

```
Max Date = MAX('Monitor Orders'[Run Date])
```

This measure is unaffected by the slicer and is always the most recent date in the report. My problem is that CALCULATE doesnt allow boolean filter conditions that reference measures. So I cannot do:

```
At Risk on Last Run = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Monitor Orders'[Order #]),'Monitor Orders'[Type] = "At Risk",'Monitor Orders'[Run Date] = [Max Date])
```

How would you approach solving for this?

Thank you.